# Posso herdar namespaces?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, composer, namespace

Estou usando `composer` com autoload nos namespaces das classes, supondo que eu tenha a classe pai **Model**:

**Model.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use App\Utils;
use \PDO;

class Model {}
```

E a classe filha **Item**:
**Item.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

class Item extends Model {}
```

Teria alguma maneira de eu "herdar" também as importações dos namespaces da classe pai(`App\Utils` e `\PDO`)?

Pergunto pois eu necessitaria usar várias classes que utilizam `App\Utils` e `\PDO`, e gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de não precisar repetir toda vez a declaração do `use` em cada classe.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisei e estudei sobre assunto, e não encontrei uma forma "concreta" de herdar `namespasces`. Devido a isso, irei fazer a utilização de vários `namespaces` na mesma linha:

```
<?php
namespasce App\Principal;

use App\Exemplo\{NamespaceUm, NamespaceDois, NamespaceTres}

...
```